# How to use cell value as it appears in Excel?

Tags: excel, formatting, spreadsheet

I have an excel spread sheet when a cell with the value 0.00255
But I have the source formatting round the number to three sig figs and display to 4 decimal places.
So the value in the cell is now 0.0026

I then want to use this rounded value in subsequent calculations, but instead the calculations used 0.00255, not 0.0026. I want the calculations to use 0.0026. How do I do this?

As an example

```
Lets say cell A1 = =ROUND(.00255,3-1-INT(LOG10(ABS(0.00255))))
```

So A1 will display as 0.0026

But now I want to use 0.0026 in my equations, not 0.00255

Comment: Well I don't just have A1 rounded to 4, I actually have a complicated equation for that cell, and I have it display 3 sig figs and 4 decimal points.

Comment: If the cell is already rounded in A1 there is no need to do anything else other then `=A1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the Round function:

```
    Round(cell, digits after zero)
```

for example:

```
    Round(G5, 4)
```

Comment: I edited the question now. Round to 3 sig figs display 4 decimal places

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `rng.Text` to pickup value for your calculation.

Example

`Range("A1").Text` will give you `0.0026`

Comment: This didn't work. I just get the message, "This formula you typed contains an error" For information about fixing common formula problems, etc

Comment: Formula? You are doing this in Excel or VBA?

Comment: Excel, stackoverflow suggested I add the VBA tag when I created my question, I am not sure what VBA is

Comment: I have removed the VBA tag. VBA is Visual basic for Application. Read about it in msdn. If you are doing it via formulas then you will have to use `Round()`